# Updating Ruby Version in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on my macOS where I am trying to update the version of Ruby I am using within a project from ruby 2.0.0p648 to a newer version of Ruby (I have tried a number of different versions).  I have tried much of the information on this site to make the updates from this site and others, but no luck.

I have tried:

1. curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable –ruby
2. rvm install ruby-2.4.0
3. rvm use ruby-2.4.0 --default

But when checking that I am using / installed 2.4.0 by using ruby -v, it still comes back with 2.0.0p648.

When I run those commands via the Apple Terminal the response I receive from asking for the version comes back with 2.4.0.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Try launching VS Code from command line as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53909829/12222988

Answer (score 2):

If your project has a gemfile with the ruby version specified, then RVM will pick it up when you CD to the project folder from command line. VS code doesn't seem to do this till I added "cwd" to the launch config and then it works as expected. Here is my launch.json:

```json
    {
      // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
      // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
      // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Rails server",
          "type": "Ruby",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
          "args": [
            "server"
          ],
          "useBundler": true,
          "showDebuggerOutput": true,
          "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac, but since RVM is available on Linux, I've tried working with it in WSL, as well as Windows with Railsinstaller, so I have some experience.

Actually, this isn't even about VS Code, but MAYBE, since Mac has an old Ruby version available not contained within the version manager, this happens.

First of all, note all the available versions (inside RVM, well as the one which is shown by the terminal), and uninstall all versions outside of RVM.

Keep this with you just for backup, if incase, anything goes wrong, you can reinstall them.

Next try setting the preferred Ruby version using RVM.

Try finding out the Ruby version

```sh
ruby -v
```

If that matches your description, you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely, it about your IDE's config about ruby-path, find where can set ruby-path and set the correct rvm-ruby-path.

Comment: How do you do that in VS Code?  When I update the ruby.interpreter.commandPath with "ruby.interpreter.commandPath": "/Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0", it still shows the older version after running ruby -v.

Comment: I used Sublime Text, not VS Code, I just infer the problem what you happen.