# RVM not working properly in VS Code Debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

I'm using RVM to manage Ruby versions where I work. We have two Rails repos, one Desktop and one Mobile. The Desktop repo uses Ruby 2.2.4 and the Mobile repo uses 2.2.2.

I know that RVM has the functionality of automatically switching the appropriate Ruby version which is specified in the Gemfile (which is specified in our case in both the Gemfiles).

Now, when I use the default terminal, and run the `ruby -v` command, inside individual project root directories, it displays the appropriate versions. But when I do the same in VS terminal, it displays the default version, which is 2.2.4.

Now my main problem was that the Rails debugger was giving me the following error: `Your Ruby version is 2.2.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2` for the Mobile repo whenever I tried to use the VS Debugger. And I suspect that it is because of whatever I've mentioned above.

Is that the case or is it a different issue? Also provide the solution for whatever the issue is.

Answer (score 15):

Found the solution for the version issue. Turns out that if you open VS Code through the GUI, then VS Code uses the default version of Ruby. But if you open it with the CLI by going inside the directory of the project and then typing `code .`, it works with the version specified in the Gemfile.

My guess is that RVM does a Ruby version switch when you `cd` into the project directory and because of which VS Code uses that switched version because the instance of VS Code was created by the same process which did the switch. ***Note:** I don't know much about Linux processes so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.*

Comment: That is very helpful. If anyone knows a way to switch gemset from inside a GUI opened window of VS Code, please post an answer as well.

Comment: This makes sense but this is exactly how I do it and everything ruby related running within vscode is using `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/`. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 5):

With `rvm` you have two choices:

1. Open workspace from your terminal with `code .` command. This ensures that appropriate paths are set. But when you open another workspace from UI, appropriate paths will not be set.
2. Set paths inside your `launch.json` yourself as follows:

```json
{
    "name": "Rails server",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
    "env": {
        "PATH": "",
        "GEM_HOME": "",
        "GEM_PATH": "",
        "RUBY_VERSION": "ruby-2.5.3"
    },
    "args": [
        "server"
    ]
}
```

Both solutions are cumbersome and what I recommend is to uninstall `rvm` and use `rbenv` for ruby versions management instead.

With `rbenv` you don't have to specify paths and you can open your worskpaces directly from UI - correct ruby versions and paths will be always set. Using `rbenv` even resolved other issues with vscode I previously had with rubocop and solargraph extensions.

Interesting article for other benefits replacing `rvm` with `rbenv`:
https://dev.to/krtb/why-and-how-i-replaced-rvm-with-rbenv-23ad

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting for the command path of the ruby interpreter that defaults to just "ruby".  I'm just getting into vscode, but it may be possible to use a vscode variable interpolation to the rvm command and set the ruby interpreter value to the rvm result.

Has anyone used https://github.com/ngetahun/vscode-rvm?

Comment: Is it answer or additional question?

Answer (score 1):

Works following

settings.json:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
            "args": ["--login"]         // <--- Enables RVM at the terminal in VSCODE
        }
    }
}
```

.bash_profile:

```
...

# This activates current Ruby version in terminal as RVM triggers 
# versions by command CD, but VSCODE opens terminal already in work directory
cd .
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "rdbg",
            "name": "Debug current file with rdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "bin/rails",    // <--- Rails instead of default Ruby
            "script": "server",
            "args": [],
            "askParameters": false,
            "useTerminal": true    // <--- Opens bash terminal instead of Debug Console
        }
    ]
}
```

After this you can start and debug Rails application with configuration "Debug current file with rdbg" and correct RVM environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can type this code on terminal project folder to get the exact "env" config then past the result on the launch.json

```
printf "\n\"env\": {\n  \"PATH\": \"$PATH\",\n  \"GEM_HOME\": \"$GEM_HOME\",\n  \"GEM_PATH\": \"$GEM_PATH\",\n  \"RUBY_VERSION\": \"$RUBY_VERSION\"\n}\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to you launch config:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
```

Or see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64597596/12222988